# How to transform PHP logic to open social media share in new window?

Tags: php, wordpress, share, social-media, new-window

In one part of my wordpress blog's theme, the social media share for posts is generated dynamically. How would I get this to open in a new window?

One of my static HTML share `<a>` tags that opens in a new window:

```
<a title='Share on Facebook' href='#' onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=staging.example.org','mywindow','width=600,height=600');">
Share
</a>
```

Example of the dynamic PHP I'd like to do the same:

```
if(themeple_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'twitter_link') != '')
$output .= '<li class="twitter">
<a href="'.themeple_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'twitter_link').'" title="Twitter"><i class="moon-twitter"></i></a>
</li>';
```

Comment: Add `_target="blank"` attribute to your `a` tag (if I understood your claim properly.)

Comment: @mudasobwa that runs the risk of only opening in a new tab. I'm trying to make sure the link will open in a new window (as `window.open` does).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming WordPress isn't already outputting a JavaScript URL... just wrap the output that's being put in the `href` tag with `javascript:window.open()`, like this:

```
if(themeple_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'twitter_link') != '')
$output .= '<li class="twitter">
    <a href="javascript:window.open(\''.themeple_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'twitter_link').'\');" title="Twitter"><i class="moon-twitter"></i></a>
    </li>';
```

Comment: Looks like it should work, but is still only opening in a new tab for me.

Comment: Then that's your browser misusing `window.open`, not the JavaScript. Some browsers are set so that new *windows* open in a new *tab*, regardless of how it is invoked.